# CSS grid fixed responsive columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a responsive grid with:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 10px 10px;
```

How can I set the max number of columns to be four, while maintaining responsivity? That is, when the page is resized, the rows should collapse into one column as in the example, but have a max size of four columns.

So,

```
repeat(4, 1fr);
```

will not work.

Do I have to use flexbox? I've seen related answers on SO but none seem to explain it clearly.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/m55zx55nkj).

Comment: instead of auto-fit use 4

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I do this, I lose responsivity.

Comment: Colin, what does responsivity means for you? Because when you do `auto-fit` -> `4`, during resize the cols change size properly. But they are always in the row.

Comment: Responsive like the example code is. i.e. resizing the page collapses into one column.

Comment: Have you looked into media queries?

Comment: `How can I set the max number of columns to be four, while maintaining responsivity ?` what responsivity are we talking about here exactly ? having a fixed value has never been a way of doing responsive designs.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa responsive, in that when there's room for > 4 columns, there is only four, and when there's room for less than 4, it collapses to 1 column, as with the regular grid auto-fit.

Comment: @Colin as per some other responses.  Using media queries makes the most sense to me.  Just change your `gird-template-columns` properties for each breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set the max number of columns to be four, while maintaining
>   responsivity?

As hinted by @Powell_v2 in the comments - You will need to set a media query to modify the value for the `grid-template-columns` property when the maximum number of columns are reached.

Using the OP's example, on narrow viewport widths (where we have less than the maximum number of columns) we want responsive columns - so we can use the OP's code for the `grid-template-columns` property:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr))`

However, when we reach the maximum number of columns we want the grid to stop being responsive - at this point a media query should kick in to modify the value for `grid-template-columns`.

We can calculate this break-point - assuming the grid takes up the whole viewport - as follows:

```
max number of cols * min column width + (max number of cols -1) * column gap
```

So here it will be: 400px + 30px = 430px

At this point - we don't want additional columns - we just want the columns to be the same width.

```
@media (min-width: 430px) {
  .wpr {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

So the solution will look something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wpr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
}
.wpr > div {
  border: 5px solid green;
  min-height: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 430px) {
  .wpr {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/JvOEqM) (Resize to see the effect)

**NB:** We can take advantage of a preprocessor such as SASS to achieve a more general and reusable solution:

```
// Set custom values for 1) Minimum Column width 2) Maximum # columns 3) Gap size

$min-col-width: 150;
$max-cols: 5;
$gap-size: 30;
$break-point: $min-col-width * $max-cols + $gap-size * ($max-cols - 1) * 1px;
```

### [Codepen Demo with SCSS](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/zjPwLg) (Resize)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that You want to limit the maximum width of the grid, so the columns will fit based on that?

If the column is in minimal size of `100px`, then the max-width of grid can be set to `430px` (considering also the gaps on side):

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;

  max-width: 430px;
`;
```

To fit full screen, You can just raise the limits of minimal value to be `/4` of grid width.